# Intersection of all layers of different feature classes using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, select-by-location, intersect

I have 20 different layers where a few of the layers are lines ( rivers) some are points and a few are polygons. I need to find all the single polygons where all 20 layers intersect as describe:

> - within distance 10 meters of layer #1
> - within distance 20 meters of layer #2.
> - ... ...
> - within distance 100 meters of layer #20.

I have ArcMap 10.7 with a license that allows doing multiple-layer intersections. I use two methods:

1. Buffer (with dissolved) each layer by the distance and feed all in a intersect in my model.
2. I buffer the first one and I use "select by distance" within the distance specified by the next layer and keep doing this to layer 20!

But none of the methods returns a correct result.

Is this because the layers are from different feature classes?

Comment: Are you getting the result you expect when you do this just using a polygon and a line layer?  If not, then I recommend investigating why not, before introducing point layers and more line and polygon layers into your process.

Comment: Try union on 3 buffers. Select where all 3 finds <> -1

Comment: why -1 please? are we finding the gaps? I want to overlap of all!